# APK file doesnt recognize the external lib

Tags: android, apk

Im quite new about Android, im doing an simple app which displays 20 tweets, the problem is when I run my app on eclipse everything is just fine, but when I build to an apk file to run on my phone there is an error occurs. Here's what I have done so far and the problem occurs in this method:

```
public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String searchTerm, int page) {
        String searchUrl = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json?count=3&include_entities=true";
        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        String responseBody = null;
        try {
            responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Object obj = JSONValue.parse(responseBody); // problem here
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
                JSONObject o = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                JSONObject user = (JSONObject) o.get("user");
                Tweet tweet = new Tweet(user.get("name").toString(), o.get(
                        "text").toString(), user.get("profile_image_url")
                        .toString());
                tweets.add(tweet);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(PullToRefreshListViewSampleActivity.this,
                    "Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        return tweets;
    }
```

Im using the org.json.simple jar for the JSON function, I realize that when I build to the apk file, the jar isnt included. Can anyone has solution for this? Sorry about my English, its not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse.
The go into project configurations - build path - import/export, and make sure your jar file is marked so it is exported when you build. :-)